# Error: Failed to Load Resources - in tomcat

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, tomcat, directory

I have developed a gallery section where the user can slide images. The functionality is working fine. But the tomcat server is failing to find the image files. According to the directory structure, it seems the URL is ok where container should get the images but it's showing file not found error.

I have added the error and also my directory structure.

This is the error

https://www.dropbox.com/s/blx0d4ftowfhnwz/Capture.PNG?dl=0

This is the directory structure

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sicqzvvhcr1eu3w/01.PNG?dl=0

The container can only able to load 9.jpg and 12.jpg files.

This is the code to load images

```
var Gallery_Images = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7.jpg","8.jpg","9.jpg","10.jpg","11.jpg","12.jpg","13.jpg"];
var path = "Static/Resources/Gallery_Images/";

$(this).children(1).attr("src",path+Gallery_Images[val]);
```

I have also tried to map the mime type in web.xml.But that didn't solve the problem.

```
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>JPG</extension>
  <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<mime-mapping>
  <extension>jpg</extension>
  <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

It would be great if someone helps me on this.Thanks

Comment: The value you are setting to 'src' does not contain the context root though the error message does

Comment: It seems Apache Tomcat is case-sensitive that's why it didn't work at first.
But after only deploying As a war file, it's working in all browsers, without war file it's only working in google chrome. 
Pretty weird.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this kind of issue occurs when the publishing didn't happen properly, because the server is able to load couple of images but not others.

Suggest you to build a war file and deploy to see if this issue persists.

Comment: It worked after deploying as war file after I changed the extension to lowercase .jpg.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the file extension. The unloaded images extension is in upper case. So I suggest you to try by changing the extension to lowercase. Check the below image.

[image]

Another solution I can give you(but I don't recommend this personally because I strongly advice to have filenames and as well as extensions in lower case.)

> var Gallery_Images =
>   ["1.jpg",***"2.JPG","3.JPG","4.JPG","5.JPG","6.JPG","7.JPG","8.JPG",***"9.jpg",***"10.JPG","11.JPG",***"12.jpg",***"13.JPG"***];

Comment: I've replaced all the file extension from uppercase to lowercase (.jpg). But I'm still getting the problem  :/

Comment: I feel this solution must be working. Not sure why it is not working in your case.

Comment: Your solution is working in google chrome. But in Mozilla, opera I'm still getting the error. 
However, according to **S R Chaitanya** I've created a war file it also didn't work at first. After changing all the extension to lowercase I created a war file again and now it's working in all browsers.
So both answers gave a solution to this problem I think.
But it seems pretty much weird to me why it's only working in google chrome without war file.